# The preformatted text/code text font in chat is not sufficiently distinct

Tags: feature-request, chat

In chat, when putting text between grave accents to ensure that it is output as `code`, the resulting text is not very distinguishable from the other text:

[image]

The only way it's different, right now, is that a different font is used. Is there any way we could

- highlight it
- make it a different color
- make it a more different font
- resize it

or some combination thereof?